# ubuntu eth0 up but not online

Tags: networking, ubuntu, configuration

I've been installing an Ubuntu Server on a local machine. Ive configured the eth0 in the interfaces (Static) and I can ping the router aswell as other machines in the network can ping the server and even get the apache default-site. So I assume, that eth0 is configured correct. I can't however update or search via apt-get, so I think, that means, that the machine is currently offline. Has anybody some pointers, what I might have missed?
Regards,
Marcus

Answer (score 1):

My guess is: DNS settings in resolv.conf . By changing it to DHCP, the machine got the information via the DHCP Server.

Comment: Seconding this!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the config to dhcp, restarted the network, changed back to static again and ever thing works fine now. No idea why, though.